# Upcoming journals and conferences: read 'em and ask on the Stack (and get prizes)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As the new monthly issues of your favorite journals are published and *conferences* approach, we want to remind you to ask those burning questions that pop into your head as you read through *novel approaches, methods and cutting edge or controversial findings*. Stack Exchange consists of remarkably bright and talented researchers and our community benefits greatly from more current and relevant questions. **When you flip through your favorite journal, proceedings or at a conference and are downright astonished by some findings or perplexed by a method, share that curiosity here.**

Staying up to date in the field betters your own expertise and sharing those quandaries with your peers furthers the discipline as a whole. To encourage good ole fashioned journal reading (*winks at open access*) **users who ask questions about the current issues of whatever journal they like on the Stack are eligible for a drawing to win a year long subscription to a journal** of their choosing (excluding obscure journals only in print in Kazakhstan with a zillion dollar fee) OR assistance in attending a conference. Before Christmas, all posts referencing (denoted with "citation") a current publication will be entered in the drawing and a random winner of all winners will be announced (plus secondary prizes).

*Updated: Includes topics from conference proceedings, conference lectures. Prize will include assistance in attending a conference or journal subscription.

Comment: Man, you guys are coming up with promotions faster than we can do anything about them. I'd recommend though that for theoryCS, you extend this to conferences, since that's where most of our action is.

Comment: For TCS, you should also consider Conferences. In fact, conferences proceedings are the main dissemination medium in our field.

Comment: Good point, thanks. Updated.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, @SethRogers.

Comment: I thought we discouraged questions with approximate content "I don't get X from Paper A, please explain!". So we mainly talk about follow-up questions like alternative approaches?

Comment: For this promotion, we might be OK with relaxing that rule.